# Smooth expand/collapse transition using vue transition considering dynamic content heights

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, transition

I’m facing some trouble with vue transitions, maybe some of you could help me out?! What I want to realise is a simple, lightweight collapse component using vue transitions.

Therefore in my current approach each time the collapse is collapsing the height of it should be set to `contentHeight` and then immediately after this to `0` (as well as the other way round when expanding). Or to speak in vue transition’s JavaScript hooks:

- before-enter: set height to `0`
- enter: set height to `contentHeight`
- after-enter: set height to `auto`
- before-leave: set height to `contentHeight`
- leave: set height to `0`

This is the current approach:

```html
<template>
  <transition
    @before-enter="beforeEnter"
    @enter="enter"
    @after-enter="afterEnter"
    @before-leave="beforeLeave"
    @leave="leave"
    @after-leave="afterLeave"
  >
    <div
      v-if="isCollapsed === false"
      :style="componentStyles"
      class="UiCollapse"
    >
      <div 
        ref="content"
        class="UiCollapse-content"
      >
        <slot/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "UiCollapse",

  props: {
    isCollapsed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      componentStyles: {
        height: undefined
      }
    };
  },

  methods: {
    beforeEnter() {
      this.setHeight(0);
    },

    enter() {
      this.setHeight(this.getContentHeight());
    },

    afterEnter() {
      this.setHeight(undefined);
    },

    beforeLeave() {
      this.setHeight(this.getContentHeight());
    },

    leave() {
      this.setHeight(0);
    },

    afterLeave() {
      this.setHeight(0);
    },

    setHeight(height) {
      this.componentStyles.height = height;
    },

    getContentHeight() {
      return this.$refs.content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.UiCollapse {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.UiCollapse.v-enter-active,
.UiCollapse.v-leave-active {
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

.UiCollapse-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

With this approach dynamic heights of the content and content changes affecting its height should be considered.

I also transferred this to a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/yq1nw51yq9

What I would expect here was a smooth opening and closing transition (as defined in css), but as you can see in this project this is working only partially and I do not understand why. Does any of you have any ideas?

Maybe this is not the correct approach, I’m open minded for alternative approaches or already existing libs (though I would prefer to understand vue transitions here), but the solutions I found so far were using fix values for `max-height` or other workarounds I’d like to avoid.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What about an expansion panel component ? I'm not sure what you really wanna do but it may help you at least. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion. 

The collapse component described above should be reusable in other components and shouldn't have any own style (except the necessary `height` and `overflow`) and only be responsible for a collapse/expand transition of any dynamic content. A bit similar to [vue-collapse](https://github.com/roszpun/vue-collapse), but without a fix `max-height` and a more simplified functionality.